# Do maven create a duplicate of css file?

Tags: css, apache, maven, jsp, tomcat

I'm working on a web project and I get stuck on a reccurent problem. Each two days of work, one of my css file doesn't apply any change on the jsp file it is linked in. I can comment every css parameters of the file and it will still don't change anything. The only way a modification can occur is when I comment the link in the jsp file. Anyone had this problem and know what happens, like do maven or tomcat copy my css file somewhere and don't refer to the one I'm working on?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do a hard refresh - just press ctrl + f5 as the browser caches it so you need to force it to re-download

Answer (score 0):

Well for every next fool like me, it was a cache problem. Just clean your tomcat server and it should work fine. (To my defense it's only the second time I cleaned it that it worked)